# Create a sticky sidebar with Visual Composer (WordPress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I want to create a sticky sidebar with my WordPress site. Sadly I cannot add more IDs and Classes to my divs because there is no way with Visual Composer. This is already everything I can get out.

I am using the Sticky Sidebar plugin which I found on GitHub:
https://abouolia.github.io/sticky-sidebar/

I have embeded the script as described in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://classymagazin.de/sticky-sidebar.js"></script>
```

And this is my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sidebar = new StickySidebar('#sidebarContainer', {
        containerSelector: '#sidebarContainer',
        innerWrapperSelector: '#stickySocialIcons',
        topSpacing: 20,
        bottomSpacing: 20
    });
</script>
```

But my problem is, I always get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: StickySidebar is not definedat (index):186

How can I fix this problem and get my sidebar sticky?

My sidebar is `#sidebarContainer` on this website: https://classymagazin.de/home/

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You can write in document ready like this

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){var sidebar = new StickySidebar('#sidebarContainer', {containerSelector: '#sidebarContainer',
    innerWrapperSelector: '#stickySocialIcons',
    topSpacing: 20,
    bottomSpacing: 20});});
```

Comment: I show this js not found ghr2xom.js in your web page can you check it?